# How to filter datatable with value add with jquery

Tags: datatable

I'm using Datatable and I am trying to filter value on my last td column on text Red or white value..

When I clicked on arrow's filter nothing is happening (no filter action)..

Do you know why?

[image exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC7sX.png)

```
 $('#sst-table-all-contracts').DataTable 
                            ({
                            'createdRow': function (row, data) {
                                $(row).find("td:eq(1)").attr("id", data[6]);
                                
                                if (data[7] == null )
                                {
                                    $(row).find('td:last').css("background", "white");
                                    $(row).find('td:last').text("white");
                                    $(row).find('td:last').css("color", "white");

                                }
                                else {
                                
                                    $(row).find('td:last').css("background", "red");
                                    $(row).find('td:last').text("red");
                                    $(row).find('td:last').css("color", "red");
                                
                                }
                                
                                },
                            "aaData": contractsList,
                            "aoColumns": [ {}, {}]

                                  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by "arrow's filter nothing is happening"?

Comment: on click on filter on header , data are not filter on text field value

Comment: I think you're clicking on sort up and down arrows. can you edit question with screenshot?

Comment: like I said, the arrow is for sorting and not filtering.